# Swift In App Subscription How to check active status?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

This question might have been asked but I did not find a good solution for me.

So: If I want to check if a user is subscribed in my app for a week or month, is there a specific value that says "active" true / false OR do I have to calculate it in code by checking the current timestamp with the start of subscription?

Like: `currentDate - dateSubscribed = daysRemaining

I saw codesampes but I could not determine it from the samples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost. You should check against the `expiration_date` field and compare that against the current date.

Ideally, you compare the date against a server time instead of the device time which the user can easily change.

If you want a deeper read of checking subscription status for users check out: [iOS Subscriptions are Hard](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f)

Comment: Thanks so much. thats all I wanted to know lol...so no "easy" way :) But I was not aware that device time can be manipulated that easy.